# Is there was a mechanism in Windows works like message queue in Linux?

Tags: c, windows, message

Recently, I got a job(C/C++) to use message communication between different threads in Windows. I Googled and find that the Windows also got a message queue too, but it is more related to a window, actually, I do not need any window in my application.

Like the message queue in Linux, each thread create a message queue and got a message queue ID, sending message to that ID, receive from that ID and so on, that is the message queue I need.

Is there any similar mechanism(s) in Windows works like that?

Comment: Does your employer expect you to find [RabbitMq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or similar tools or are you tasked with re-creating the `mq_send()` POSIX-specified interface? What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Doesn't Qt do this sort of thing, or I am totally off in the weeds here? (I have no experience with Qt).

Comment: Even if you don't need a window, you also can create a *message-only* window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a window to use messages on Windows, any thread that calls PeekMessage or GetMessage gets a message queue and you can post messages to it with [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Messages should work fine in the same process but if this is cross-process and you need to send more than size_t*2 you should look at other [IPC mechanisms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or build your own with shared memory and some type of locking. Windows also has [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing).

You did not specify if you need the exact POSIX interface or not, either way, Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) of open source alternatives...